# Using Scrapy to Scrape Content after a particular keyword/string

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape content after the occurrence of a particular keyword/string.

Suppose the Xpath is as follows:

```
   <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.example.com/tshirt/pcid111-31">
   <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.example.com/tshirt/pcid3131-33">
   <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.example.com/tshirt/pcid545424524-84">
```

1) How can I extract all the data inside the `content` element whose `property="og:url`

2)I also want to extract anything which is after the `pcid`, can someone suggest a way around this?

Now sure if this would work:

item ["example"] =sel.xpath("//meta[@property='og:url']/text()").extract()[0].replace("*pcid","")

Does the replace take in wildcard character references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will extract `content` attributes of elements whose `property="og:url"`

```
og_urls = response.xpath("//meta[@property='og:url']/@content").extract()
```

For extracting stuff from the url it's usually best to use regex, in your case it would be:

```
for url in og_urls:
   id = re.findall("pcid(.+)")  # "pcid(.+)" = any characters after 'pcid'(greedy)
   # re.findall() returns a list and you probably want only the first occurrence and there mostlikely only be one anyway
   id = id[0] if id else ''  
   print(id)
```

or you can split the url at the 'pcid' and take the later value, e.g.

```
for url in og_urls:
   id = url.split('pcid')[-1]
   print(id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
x=len(hxs.select("//meta/@content").extract())

for i in range(x):
    print    hxs.select("//meta/@content").extract()[i].split('pcid')[1]
```

Output:

111-31

3131-33

545424524-84